# Show that the intersection of all the neighbourhoods of a point $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is the singleton set {a}

Tags: real-analysis

This one is quite simple, using the method of contradiction. Taking $\varepsilon=|a-b|$ ($a \ne b$) and eventually showing that $|a-b|$ is less than $\varepsilon$ implies that b does not belong to $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$. Here's a picture of my textbook solved problem
 [image: Problem]
Here goes my alternative approach. Is the procedure at all valid? If yes, what corrections are needed?
[image: Alternative]

Comment: At the end you say: "As $\varepsilon_i$ is continous,..." That doesn't make any sense. The $\varepsilon_i$ are just numbers, not functions.

Comment: @Mathematician42 yeah, i am aware of that. But, in this case, I tried to say that, those epsilons can be taken extremely closely

Comment: The idea is correct, but you need to formulate it correctly.

Comment: @Mathematician42 could you please write it all together, using the approach made?? It'll be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Mathematician42 can this be done using nested intervals??? (Try not to, I am not so familiar with it right now)

Answer (score 3):

You are close to a solution, but let's formulate is correctly.

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. We will show that $\bigcap N(a)=\left\{a\right\}$ where the interesection runs over all neighbourhoods of $a$.

Now by definition $a\in N(a)$ for any neighbourhood, hence $\bigcap N(a)\supset\left\{a\right\}$.

Conversely, notice that for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have that $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ is a neighbourhood of $a$. Thus for any $\varepsilon >0$, we have $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\supset \bigcap N(a)$. Equivalently, 
$$\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\supset \bigcap N(a).$$

It is a straightforward exercise to show that $\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)=\left\{a\right\}$. All together this shows both inclusions and we are done.

Comment: What exactly is $N(a)$ here? If $N(a):=\{U\mid U\text{ neighborhood of }a\}$ then indeed $\cap N(a)=\{a\}$ but by definition $a\in\cap N(a)$ and not $a\in N(a)$ as you state. In my view the question itself causes confusion by stating that $\{N(a)\}$ is the *family* of all neighborhoods of $a$. I think it is better only to state that $N(a)$ is the *collection* of all neighborhoods of $a$.

Comment: @drhab: I agree, the notation isn't very good. I viewed $N(a)$ as a notation for a neighbourhood of $a$ and the intersection runs over all $N(a)$ such that $N(a)$ is a neighbourhood of $a$, but this is not reflected in the notation. Your suggestion solves the issue though.