# Doubt regarding a proof of intersection of the set of all neighbourhoods of a point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is the singleton set $\{x\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

This is the exact same question as posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2431433/697421). I was trying a different approach for solving this problem, but seem to have run into a dead end.

**My approach:** Let there be n such neighbourhoods of the point $x$ and let us denote them by $\left(a_1,b_1\right),\left(a_2,b_2\right),\left(a_3,b_3\right)...,\left(a_n,b_n\right)$. Thus $x$ is bounded above by $b_j$ and bounded below by $a_i$ $\forall i,j=1,2,...,n$.

Let us define a sequence $A_n:=\text{max}\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n\}$. Clearly, $A_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence bounded above by $x$.

Define another sequence $B_n:=\text{min}\{b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_n\}$. Now this is a non-increasing sequence bounded below by $x$.

Thus, by **Monotone Convergence Theorem**, both $A_n$ and $B_n$ converges to some $A,B \left(\in \mathbb{R}\right)$ respectively. We can also say that $A\leq x\leq B$.

The only thing left to prove is: $A=B$. I seem to have run out of ideas here.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Given what you say here, it can happen that $A<B$. To make this work you need something more, for example you could choose your sequences so $a_n\to x$ and $b_n\to x$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yeah, I get your point. Can you please help me in constructing one such sequence? Any hints?

Comment: you really can't think of a sequence converging to $x$? Try $a_n=x-\frac1n$. Think about $b_n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich oh, you're taking $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ in this case... I now understand this. Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A<x$ and observe that $(\frac {A+x}2,x+42)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Oh, and this is a contradiction to the fact that $A=\text{sup}A_n$, right?

Comment: @DebarthaPaul Yes. Then again, it also **directly** shows that $A<x$ is not in the intersection of all neighbourhoods of $x$, regardless of what $A$ is (as long as it is $<x$)

Comment: Yaa, I get it...Thank you